# AchartEngine when zooming in linechart lines disappear

Tags: achartengine

I am using AchartEngine to draw graph with multiple lines (linechart). When zooming in, lines between points disappear and only points stay visible. Did anyone had such problem ?

[image]

[image]

Code is nothing special.

XYMultipleSeriesDataset mDataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

```
    XYSeries IVseries=new XYValueSeries("IV");
    XYSeries IV_stc_series=new XYValueSeries("IVstc");


    for(double i=0;i<6;i=i+0.1){
        IVseries.add(sin(i),cos(i));
        IV_stc_series.add(2*sin(i),cos(i));
    }

    mDataset.addSeries(IVseries);
    mDataset.addSeries(IV_stc_series);

    XYSeriesRenderer IVrenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer ();
    IVrenderer.setFillPoints(true);
    IVrenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.TRIANGLE);
    IVrenderer.setLineWidth(5);
    IVrenderer.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(IVrenderer);

    XYSeriesRenderer IV_stc_renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer ();
    IV_stc_renderer.setFillPoints(true);
    IV_stc_renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.X);
    IV_stc_renderer.setLineWidth(5);
    IV_stc_renderer.setColor(Color.RED);
    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(IV_stc_renderer);

    mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true,true);
    mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(true, true);
    mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
    mRenderer.setXLabels(20);
    mRenderer.setYLabels(20);
    mRenderer.setShowGrid(true);
    mRenderer.setGridColor(Color.BLACK);
    mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

    mChartView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(context, mDataset, mRenderer);
    layout.addView(mChartView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Comment: I haven't seen it. What version of AChartEngine are you using?

Comment: updated question to clarify things. Tried with achartengine 0.7 and 1.1. But in 1.1 i cannot create such graph (issue 247)

Comment: Please try the 1.1.0-rc2 version and let me know if it fixes the issue. You can download it here: http://www.achartengine.org/download/

Comment: It is better. When zoomed in and panning around it still happens that line disappears.

Comment: That's because points that get out of the screen are not rendered.

Comment: So when zoomed in pan should be disabled?

Comment: @Dan did you find any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually i resolved this by disabling hardware acceleration in AndroidManifest.xml

android:hardwareAccelerated="false"

This way lines are always rendered no mater how much i zoom in.

Comment: hardwareAccelerated parameter resolves the the issue but it makes dither while touching. Any other solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can also disable hardware acceleration just for a particular view with:

```
View.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

This solved my problem with achartengine. And yes, in older phones the rendering is noticeably not as smooth...

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of AbstarctChart==> calculateDrawPoint returns float array which consist sometimes Float.NaN .
Please check the post

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38568422/2732632