# AchartEngineLine Chart in android - Line disappears while panning

Tags: android, achartengine

I am facing an issue in AchartEngine Scatter chart in android. The line between each point, disappears when panning after set zoom to a level. 
I had tried hardwareAcceleration to false and setLayerType to null and all. But, issue remains.

Achartengine version 1.1.0.
Android device - Galaxy S4, S3.
Can you please help me on this ?

Screenshot is placed here at, https://i.stack.imgur.com/hq5r4.png

[image: Screenshot is pasted down - with no line between chart points]
Thanks

JRH

Comment: Post some screenshots. The scatter chart has no lines to connect the points.

Comment: Dan, I added the screenshot, can you please look into it?

Comment: I still don't understand what line you miss in a scatter plot?

Comment: Its a line chart, We used ,   (GraphicalView) ChartFactory.getLineChartView(
    getBaseContext(), dataset, multiRenderer);

Comment: sorry for that, I given a wrong title for the question.

Comment: I have no idea how to replicate the issue you have.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48077/discussion-between-jrhamza-and-dan)

Answer (score 0):

After two days of effort, I was able to solve the issue. It was due to Float.NaN for one of the Path value, while drawing the line.

Issue was AbstractChart -> drawPath method. In that calculateDrawPoints() method returns a float array, which contains Float.NaN in one case. I dont know the issue behind it. But I could overcome that with Canvas.drawLine method.

Thanks

JRH

Answer (score 0):

Its because AbstarctChart==> calculateDrawPoints() method returns float array which contains Float.NaN

Its because during calculation, sometimes value returns 0, and after dividing value with 0, we get Float.NaN
Anything divided by zero is undefined

So update your calculateDrawPoints() method code with following

```
private static float[] calculateDrawPoints(float p1x, float p1y, float p2x, float p2y,
      int screenHeight, int screenWidth) {
    float drawP1x = 0;
    float drawP1y;
    float drawP2x = 0;
    float drawP2y;

    if (p1y > screenHeight) {
      // Intersection with the top of the screen
      float m = (p2y - p1y) / (p2x - p1x);
      if (m != 0) {
        drawP1x = (screenHeight - p1y + m * p1x) / m;
      } else {
        drawP1x = (screenHeight - p1y + m * p1x);
      }
      drawP1y = screenHeight;

      if (drawP1x < 0) {
        // If Intersection is left of the screen we calculate the intersection
        // with the left border
        drawP1x = 0;
        drawP1y = p1y - m * p1x;
      } else if (drawP1x > screenWidth) {
        // If Intersection is right of the screen we calculate the intersection
        // with the right border
        drawP1x = screenWidth;
        drawP1y = m * screenWidth + p1y - m * p1x;
      }
    } else if (p1y < 0) {
      float n = p2x - p1x;
      float m = 0;
      if (n != 0) {
        m = (p2y - p1y) / n;
      } else {
        m = (p2y - p1y);
      }
      if (m != 0) {
        drawP1x = (-p1y + m * p1x) / m;
      } else {
        drawP1x = (-p1y + m * p1x);
      }
      drawP1y = 0;
      if (drawP1x < 0) {
        drawP1x = 0;
        drawP1y = p1y - m * p1x;
      } else if (drawP1x > screenWidth) {
        drawP1x = screenWidth;
        drawP1y = m * screenWidth + p1y - m * p1x;
      }
    } else {
      // If the point is in the screen use it
      drawP1x = p1x;
      drawP1y = p1y;
    }

    if (p2y > screenHeight) {
      float n = (p2x - p1x);
      float m = 0;
      if (n != 0) {
        m = (p2y - p1y) / n;
      } else {
        m = (p2y - p1y);
      }
      if (m != 0) {
        drawP2x = (screenHeight - p1y + m * p1x) / m;
      } else {
        drawP2x = (screenHeight - p1y + m * p1x);
      }

      drawP2y = screenHeight;
      if (drawP2x < 0) {
        drawP2x = 0;
        drawP2y = p1y - m * p1x;
      } else if (drawP2x > screenWidth) {
        drawP2x = screenWidth;
        drawP2y = m * screenWidth + p1y - m * p1x;
      }
    } else if (p2y < 0) {
      float n = (p2x - p1x);
      float m = 0;
      if (n != 0) {
        m = (p2y - p1y) / n;
      } else {
        m = (p2y - p1y);
      }
      if (m != 0) {
        drawP2x = (-p1y + m * p1x) / m;
      } else {
        drawP2x = (-p1y + m * p1x);
      }
      drawP2y = 0;
      if (drawP2x < 0) {
        drawP2x = 0;
        drawP2y = p1y - m * p1x;
      } else if (drawP2x > screenWidth) {
        drawP2x = screenWidth;
        drawP2y = m * screenWidth + p1y - m * p1x;
      }
    } else {
      // If the point is in the screen use it
      drawP2x = p2x;
      drawP2y = p2y;
    }
    return new float[] { drawP1x, drawP1y, drawP2x, drawP2y };
  }
```

That will resolve your issue